# Command and Conquer: Tiberium Dawn, and dinosaurs

Tags: command-and-conquer

When I was (a lot) younger, I used to play *Tiberium Dawn* at a friend's house. One day when I was around there playing, he showed me a level where you could play against dinosaurs. From memory, he had *Windows 3.1* installed and he ran the game from *DOS*.

After I installed the game recently, I was wondering if there is any way to get to this mode, or whether it was a DOS only feature?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a campaign added to the game in one of [the updates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_&_Conquer_%28video_game%29#Single-player). To start it, the game should be started with parameters `funpark -cd`. One way to do it is to create a shortcut and add them to the end of the target, behind quotation marks.
For example: `"C:\games\c&c95\c&c95.exe" funpark -cd`

Use the shortcut, start new game and choose either GDI or the Brotherhood, missions are the same.

Comment: The unofficial C&C95 v1.06 patch adds them to the Covert Operations' "New Missions" list though, making them playable without the tedious command line parameter mess (and the horribly buggy special game mode it launches), though. In fact, I believe I removed the Funpark mode in my latest version because of the tons of bugs.

Comment: Note that the -cd parameter actually activates the no-cd system built into the game, so it's not a good idea to use that on normal game installations. On a related note, the actual required parameter for the no-cd would be `-cd.`, with the dot indicating "current directory". Without a path given behind it, `-cd` has no effect whatsoever.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this page](http://cnc.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Tiberian_Dawn_Dinosaur_missions):

> The fun park missions were a small pack of missions found in the C&C directory after patch 1.6.

Comment: Actually, they were added by the game's Covert Operations expansion pack, which upgraded the DOS version of C&C to v1.20. The unofficial 1.06 patch for C&C95 (C&C95's first release version, v1.04, is equivalent to DOS C&C v1.22) adds it to the game as well, as part of the Covert Operations.